# Where should UIKit be imported into React components

Tags: reactjs, uikit

If I take my web page and split it up into header, body, footer and other sections and make React components out of each section, and if I am using uikit for the styling do i need to import uikit into each React component. Will this not really slow down the code, as the entire uikit code base has to be imported into each React component? Is there a more optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use uikit styling for each component than you must import for each react component but import only what you really need if uikit give you that option.

Build tools like webpack exist to solve problem.

[Webpack tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and [UglifyJS](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/) eliminate dead code.